# encountered "\r" in middle of line

Tags: ruby

I am building a little bot for Slack, when I try to run the file with `ruby lib/mondial.rb` it crashes... I don't understand what is going on...
I opened my files with sublim text as plain text couldn't find any problem...

```
 perso/mondial_2018/lib/mondial/live_scores.rb:1: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
    lib/mondial.rb:1:in `require_relative': perso/mondial_2018/lib/mondial/live_scores.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
    require "faye/websock...
                              ^
        from lib/mondial.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

**live_scores.rb**

```
require "net/http"
require "http"
require "faye/websocket"
require "eventmachine"
require "json"

module Mondial
  class LiveScores
   #some classes
  end
end
```

**mondial.rb**

```
require_relative "mondial/live_scores"
```

Answer (score 2):

`\r` means a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character, which is different from the `\n` [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character.

On Windows, text files conventionally end with `\r\n`. On Unix OSs including macOS, text files end with `\n`. “Warning: encountered `\r` in middle of line, treated as a mere space” means that a line had `\r` not paired with `\n`, so the Ruby interpreter decided to interpret the character as a space .

To see the `\r` control character more easily in Sublime Text 3, you can change your user setting `"draw_white_space": "selection"` to `"draw_white_space": "all"`. Then you should be able to see the `\r` in the middle of the line, and you can delete it or replace it with the appropriate character.

Comment: A very clear explanation, thanks. I have this error and have looked at the code with hidden characters turned on but cannot see the character in question.

Comment: @MSC If you can’t see the invisible character, you can try selecting a larger range of words or lines around the error, then retyping all of it. For example, if you suspect there is a `\r` in the middle of `require_relative "mondial/live_scores"`, you could select `tive "mo` and try retyping those eight characters.